# Strange difference between formatted date and original date

Tags: php

I tried to get events from google calendar. So I have trouble in time output.

```
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:m:sP", "2013-02-12T21:00:00-05:00");
    echo $date->format('H:m');
```

Output is *21:12*, but it should be 21:00. How it can be fixed?

Comment: H:m !== H:i months and minutes are different in both createFromFormat() and in format() methods

Comment: You forgot to read the documentation for the functions you're using. Oops!

Comment: I read tons of docs. Just mistyping. To my regret I can't vote down for my own post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is months. You're looking for minutes which is `i`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", "2013-02-12T21:00:00-05:00");
echo $date->format('H:i');
```